Probability Theory and Statistics Multiple Choice Question: Independence of Events in Sequential Ball Draws
There are six identical balls, labeled with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.
They are randomly drawn twice with replacement, each time drawing one ball.
Event "A" is defined as "the number of the ball drawn first is 1",
event "B" is defined as "the number of the ball drawn second is 2",
event "C" is defined as "the sum of the numbers of the balls drawn in both draws is 8",
and event "D" is defined as "the sum of the numbers of the balls drawn in both draws is 7".
The correct answer is (B).

A. Events A and C are independent of each other.
B. Events A and D are independent of each other.
C. Events B and C are independent of each other.
D. Events C and D are independent of each other.

My method is as follows:
list = Range@6
sets = Tuples[{#, #}] &@list
a = Select[sets, First@# == 1 &]
b = Select[sets, Last@# == 2 &]
c = Select[sets, Total@# == 8 &]
d = Select[sets, Total@# == 7 &]
{pa, pb, pc, pd} = Divide @@ Length /@ {#, sets} & /@ {a, b, c, d}
ac = Intersection[a, c]
ad = Intersection[a, d]
bc = Intersection[b, c]
cd = Intersection[c, d]
{pac, pad, pbc, pcd} = 
 Divide @@ Length /@ {#, sets} & /@ {ac, ad, bc, cd}
pa pc == pac
pa pd == pad
pb pc == pbc
pcd == pc pd

Are there other methods to solve this problem?

First define the ball distribution and the events
dist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}];
balls = Array[b, 2];

eventsList = {b[1] == 1, b[2] == 2, Total@balls == 8, 
   Total@balls == 7};

define options for the answer (using their LetterNumbers)
answerOptions = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};

If two events $A$ and $B$ are independent then
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A)*P(B)
$$
independenceDef[event1_, event2_] := 
 Probability[event2 && event1, balls \[Distributed] dist] == 
  Probability[event1, balls \[Distributed] dist]*
   Probability[event2, balls \[Distributed] dist]

Now find which options independent:
independenceDef @@@ Map[Part[eventsList, #] &, answerOptions, {-1}]
(*{False, True, False, False}*)

giving us option B as the correct answer.
